# Cannot see POI on Wirecloud Map Viewer

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud

We are using the Map Viewer of the fiware-wirecloud mashup to show as POIs in a world map the location of the 3D printers registered in our Fiware project. The instance of GE implementation used is the "FIWARE Lab Mashup Portal" and the POIs are are created and retrieved from the "FIWARE Lab Global Instance" of the "Orion Context Broker" (NGSI server URL--> `https://orion.lab.fiware.org:1026/`)

The application was working fine but several months ago the POIs suddenly disappeared from the map.
After looking over all the related questions in stackoverflow and other resources about this problem, we did the following:

- Update the version of the NGSI source operator from v3.0.3 to v3.0.5,
- Change the NGSI proxy URL from `http://ngsiproxy.lab.fiware.org` to `https://ngsiproxy.lab.fiware.org`, and also
- Select the option "Use the FIWARE credentials of the workspace owner" to make public the mashup for all user in the web where it is 
  embed.

The mashup started to work perfectly.

But last week we note that the mashup again failed to show points of interest. 
We've made some checking:

- There isn't a new version available of the NGSI source operator in the Marketplace. We are using the last version v3.0.5. Same with the
  "NGSI Entity to PoI" operator or the "Map viewer" widget.
- There are no changes about the NGSI server URL--> `https://orion.lab.fiware.org:1026/` or the NGSI proxy URL-->
  `https://ngsiproxy.lab.fiware.org`
- And finally we have checked the data in the public instance of the Orion Context Broker throught a curl request and the conexion to Orion and the returned json seem right.

What it might be happening?

We have looked over all the previous similar questions in stackoverflow and other sources, but this time the answers don't help us.

Thank you in advanced for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There were a temporal problem with the global Orion Context broker and it was not sending notifications (queries and other operations were working well). The context broker team is checking the global instance and should be operational in a short period of time.

> **NOTE**: Check the URL of the context broker, it should be: `http://orion.lab.fiware.org:1026/` (without the `s` of `https`).

Comment: Ok Álvaro.
Then we wait it will be resolved as soon as possible.
We remain vigilant.

Comment: Seems to be working ;-). Please, let's us know if it's working for you :).

Comment: Hi Álvaro.

We thought that everything had been solved, but this morning, creating some new POIs we realized that although the new POI appears immediately on the map, when the widget or browser window is updated, the new POI created disappears and nevermore appears on map again. 
We have verified that the new POI data are published correctly in the public instance of the Orion Context Broker. Saved data looks fine.

What is surprising is that the POIs created long time ago are displayed properly on the map.

Comment: Things are getting worse.
Today we have noticed that even old POIs are not displayed on the map. The map appears completely empty.

Moreover, we were using two widgets with this mashup, the "NGSI Browser" to locate POI on the map, and the "NGSI Updater". Both came running fine, but unfortunately today they also have stopped working. For the first one the error message is >"ConnectionError: Connection Error" and for the second "Fail querying the server: ConnectionError: Connection Error".

Comment: I'm testing your workspace (I'm guessing your user is dima3d) and seems to be currently working, maybe the ConnectionError problem was a temporal problem. Regarding the missing PoIs, maybe the problem has something to do with this [issue](https://github.com/wirecloud-fiware/ngsi-source-operator/issues/7). I will try to start fixing it tomorrow.

Comment: Ok, Alvaro.
We have already realized that it was working.
Thanks for your diligent attention.
We'll expect you give us good news.

Comment: Hi Álvaro.

I just wanted to know if any progress has been made in relation to this issue.

Comment: The issue has been fixed and we have released a [new version](https://github.com/wirecloud-fiware/ngsi-source-operator/releases/tag/3.0.6) of the ngsi-source operator. This new version is also available on FIWARE Lab through the OrionStarterKit offering :).